# creating new object inside a stream and use the setters

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create an object inside the stream but I do not want to define another constructor for the object; I would like to use the setters to put the values where needed. Is this possible?

```
pe.setExts(pDTO.getExts().stream().map(s->new P(arg1, arg2, ..., arg12)))...;
```

As you can see I have a lot of arguments and some of them requires some processing. I want to avoid doing this processing until it is necessary.

What I am looking for may be something like this (I am not sure how to write the function; I think an anonymous function would be great here):

```
pe.setExts(pDTO.getExts().stream().map(s->{
    P p = new P();
    s->setExt1(p.getExt1());
    ...
    List<V> l = p.getExt12();
    List<X> finalL = null;
    [processing list l, populating finalL]
    s->setExt12(finalL);
}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a constructor that's not there.

I'd suggest to write a method that would take the `s` variable and return a `P` one. Something like:

```
public static P generatePfromS(S s) {
     //convert S to P
}
```

and then you can just do:

```
pe.setExts(pDTO.getExts().stream().map(YourClass::generatePFromS).collect(toList()));
```

Comment: I think my classes don't need to know about each other. One is `P` and the other one is a data transfer object `PDTO`. Doing your way, it means to create a third class which will contain that conversion method. Another thing here is that I am trying to use this stream inside a `PPDTOAdapter`. Or should I create that method inside the adapter and call it from there?

Comment: Based on your solution, I've given myself the answer in my previous comment. Thank you!